# Need To uncompress the initramfs file

Tags: linux, boot, kernel, initrd

I am new to this Linux  Kernel and I am trying to boot a board from the usb and I was sucessfull

Now My problem is the usb has two files 
a) initramfs.cpio.xz 
b) linux.img

Now what I need to do it 
decompress this initramfs and add some files to this file system  and then compress it back

I am facing issue while u uncompression any one who Know how to do it will be really helpfull to me

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and solve it based on [How to view, change, recreate Linux initrd.img file](http://fibrevillage.com/sysadmin/598-how-to-view-change-recreate-linux-initrd-img-file).

First of all, since version 2.6 and above (see [here](https://wiki.debian.org/fr/Initrd)) initrd image is simply initramfs (just the name has been kept). Then, kernel image is a simple gzip file containing a cpio archive (at least for debian).

### File format

Verify that the image in */boot* (which looks like *initrd.img.other_info*, for example : *initrd.img-4.9.0-8-686-pae*) is a gzip file

```
file initrd.img-4.9.0-8-686-pae
>> initrd.img-4.9.0-8-686-pae: gzip compressed data, was "newinitrd", last modified: Sat Apr 27 10:03:57 2019, from Unix
```

Even if the extension is *gzip* the file cannot be uncompressed directly because of the lack of *.gz* at the end of it (which here implies that we need to convert the file into a recognizable format for uncompression process)

### Uncompression

### *GZIP part*

The next step is to get the correct shape for the file with :

```
mv initrd.img-4.9.0-8-686-pae initrd.img-4.9.0-8-686-pae.gz
```

Notice that just renaming the file *initrd.img-4.9.0-8-686-pae* into *initrd.img-4.9.0-8-686-pae.gz* has no effect.

Then uncompressed the file with the appropriate command (here for a gzip file) :

```
gunzip initrd.img-4.9.0-8-686-pae.gz
```

### *CPIO part*

You will obtain an cpio archive (here the file will keep the same name *initrd.img-4.9.0-8-686-pae*)

```
file initrd.img-4.9.0-8-686-pae
>> initrd.img-4.9.0-8-686-pae: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

Then to get all files into the archive use into a new folder :

```
cpio -id < ../initrd.img-4.9.0-8-686-pae
```

That's all for the uncompression part

### Compression

After editing the image you will need to compress it again.
First create a cpio archive of all these file (still in the directory used to open the cpio archive)

```
find . | cpio --create --format='newc' > ../newInitrd
```

Then, compress the archive (in the parent directory) with :

```
gzip newInitrd
```

And finally :

```
mv newInitrd.gz newInitrd.img
```

(Then you just have the rename *newInitrd.img* into *initrd.img-4.9.0-8-686-pae* and put the file in */boot*)

Answer (score 1):

initramfs is a cpio archived file which can be optionally compressed with gzip, xz or bzip2 formats.

In your case check which kind of compression is done. The compression would mostly be gzip.

```
  $ file /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-686-pae 
  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-686-pae: gzip compressed data, from Unix
```

If its a gzip compression uncompress it with gunzip utility or any other appropriate utility for the compression format. Once uncompressed use `cpio` utility to extract the archive.

```
$ cpio -id < initrd.img-3.2.0-4-686-pae 
48843 blocks
```

The archive will contain files and directories that will be required during the time of booting.